# Execute command over SSH while logging live output

Tags: ssh, bash, tee

I'm trying to log the output of a remote ssh command.

I'm current using

`ssh USER@IP | tee -a ~/random.log`

and then run the command I need to run on the remote server which then logs to random.log.

I need this to be able to run in the background, currently it exits when I quit/close terminal.

I cannot log on the remote server as it is a router with very little free space (>800kb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use screen on the local machine as well, to prevent stopping the exit if you close your terminal window.

```
screen
```

and in the screen session,

```
ssh USER@IP | tee -a ~/random.log
```

If you accidentally close the window, just use `screen -r` to reattach. Note that this will not survive a reboot of your local machine.

Comment: That sounds great. The remote command I'm running is outputting "live", e.g. `tail -f`. Will this still work?

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: screen/tmux is great. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -2):

Tested this pretty quick between two linux boxes and it seems to work alright:

```
ssh USER@IP "command_to_show_router_log" | tee -a (local_copy_filename)
```

I used "tail -f (logfile)" in the "command_to_show_router_log" but since you mentioned this is a router, your syntax might be different.

Comment: This doesn't run in the background and it's exactly the solution the OP came up with that didn't suit his needs. Read and understand the question before posting an answer.